# Logback creating duplicate logfiles filling up hard drive

Tags: java, logback

I support a solution that is using logback to generate logfiles.  The issue is that the generated logfiles are created so fast that they are filling up the hard drive and causing the system to crash.

When analyzing the created logfiles we can see that they are 5MB in size and when they roll over the next logfile is the same data from the previous one with only 15-20 trace lines added, then it will create the next one in the same format and continue at a fast rate.  Has anyone ever seen this behavior using logback?  The issue is with the esuiteStore* logs:

${esStoreLogFilePath}/esuiteStore-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log

This is not seen in our other customers and we have not been able to recreate it in our test environment (using the same SW and logback.xml).  On my system the logfiles are created correctly (the same logging is not copied into the next rollover file).  My understanding is that it should be creating 5MB rollover logfiles, and save four days worth of logging.

I am not exactly sure what version of logback I am using but I found the following in the c:\java directory.

Manifest.mf in logback-classic-0.9.26.jar file Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_16

Java(TM) 6 Update 13 6.0.130 is installed.

Logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <contextName>SSCStoreServer</contextName>
    <jmxConfigurator/>
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <file>${esStoreLogFilePath}/esuiteStore.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${esStoreLogFilePath}/esuiteStore-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <MaxHistory>4</MaxHistory>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>4</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %date %level [%thread] %logger{10}:%L %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
        <filter class="com.ncr.ssc.cf.common.util.LoggerNameFilter">
            <LoggerName>org.hibernate</LoggerName>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %date %level [%thread] %logger{10}:%L %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
        <filter class="com.ncr.ssc.cf.common.util.LoggerNameFilter">
            <LoggerName>org.hibernate</LoggerName>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="METRICS"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <file>${esStoreLogFilePath}/personalizationMetrics.csv</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>personalizationMetrics%i.csv</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>2</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>5MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
        <filter class="com.ncr.ssc.ss.personalizationcontroller.LoggerMetricsFilter">
            <LoggerName>Metrics</LoggerName>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="METRICS" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were multiple processes running trying to access the logfile so once it tried to rollover it started creating multiple logfiles with the same data.  The process list showed multiple instances of Java running.